# Attempting to scrape some information from Amazon. While implementing the next page link, a lot of data is missing

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
class A1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon"
    allowed_domains = ["www.amazon.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=golf+balls',
    )
def __init__(self):
    self.page = 0

def parse(self, response):
    self.page += 1
    #have to view the response from scrapy to determine the xpath. it is different from what the browser sees.
    #xpath
    url_x = '//*[starts-with(@id,"result_")]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/@href'

    url = response.xpath(url_x).extract()
    print len(url)

    for i in url:
        yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse_item)



    #next page
    NextBottom = response.xpath('//*[@id="pagnNextLink"]/@href').extract_first()
    NextBottom_a = response.urljoin(NextBottom)


    # print NextBottom_a

    # if self.page <= 1:
    #     yield scrapy.Request(NextBottom_a)
```

the last few lines are used to request the next page.
When I am only scraping the `start_url` (the first page of the search result), all of the 24 items show up.
When I use these lines to go to next page, most of items on the first page are missing and from the second page as well.

What are the possible reasons for this? I was thinking I encountered a robot check. However, it works perfectly on the first page only.

Comment: When amazon sees a lot of requests from an ip they force you to login, that's probably what's happening, what does your scrapy output say?

Comment: yeah with the good throttling, I think your spider should work, I think @domoarrigato's answer is valid because you are not mentioning the callback for your "next page" request, although `don_filter=True` is not necessary on this case.

Comment: @Rafael Almeida they dont actually force you to login. they have a robot check to let you enter a verification code. I am trying to use random proxy to solve the problem while crawling a rather big amount of data

Comment: @eLRuLL I was assuming that if you dont not 'callback', it will by default yield the response back to itself.

Comment: not really, it defaults to `parse` which will work for your case too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

```
yield scrapy.Request(NextBottom_a, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

to get to the next pages - while using `dont_filter` ensuring that scrapy doesn't decide you already called this url elsewhere and you don't actually need it.

Comment: Hmm, "anonymous downvoter," it would be more productive to explain how you think this answer could be improved, or why you don't feel it answers the question.

Comment: the answer is legit. now when I scrape 4 pages. there are 96 items output (24 items per page), which mean the scraping is complete.